# Downloading PS4 games

Tags: ps4

If I buy and download a game on my ps4 can I deleted it for space and download again for free or would I need to pay again.

That would be daft if I had to keep paying for the same game.

Answer (score 1):

You will not have to buy a game again.  The games you purchase are recorded to your account history and can be downloaded again, provided the game is still available for download in the future.

Comment: To download a purchased game that's been previously deleted (or never installed in the first place), you only need to check the library, which should be somewhere among the other applications.